# extracting data from for loop matlab

Tags: matlab

the problem i'm trying to solve here is how do i extract the data of x1,y1,x2,y2 as i have 5 sets of those data due to 5 planes? the data im getting in the workspace is only the last data, which is challenge for me to retrieve the data needed

```
 j = 2;

 for i = 1 : 5 % number of planes( 3D matrix ) 
    x1 = P(:,1,i); % x value
    y1 = P(:,2,i); % y value

    valid1 = y1 > 0;
    valid_fzn1 = y1(valid1);
    valid_time1 = x1(valid1);

    x2 = P(:,3,i);
    y2 = P(:,4,i);

    valid2 = y2 > 0;
    valid_fzn2 = y2(valid2); % getting data more than zero
    valid_time2 = x2(valid2); % getting data more than zero

    figure(j)
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(valid_time1,valid_fzn1,'b.')
    title('Fzn vs time(Left Leg)')
    xlabel('time(s)')
    ylabel('Fzn(N)')
    hold on

    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(valid_time2,valid_fzn2,'b.')
    title('Fzn vs time(Left Leg)')
    xlabel('time(s)')
    ylabel('Fzn(N)')
    hold on


    j = j + 1;
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the variables in which you are interested into cells in order to be able to store another 'layer' of information. In your situation, I believe something like the following will work (please note I wasn't able to see a working result without knowing P):

```
j = 2;

for i = 1 : 5 % number of planes( 3D matrix )
    x1{i} = P(:,1,i); % x value
    y1{i} = P(:,2,i); % y value

    valid1 = y1{i} > 0;
    valid_fzn1 = y1{i}(valid1);
    valid_time1 = x1{i}(valid1);

    x2{i} = P(:,3,i);
    y2{i} = P(:,4,i);

    valid2 = y2{i} > 0;
    valid_fzn2 = y2{i}(valid2); % getting data more than zero
    valid_time2 = x2{i}(valid2); % getting data more than zero

    figure(j)
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(valid_time1,valid_fzn1,'b.')
    title('Fzn vs time(Left Leg)')
    xlabel('time(s)')
    ylabel('Fzn(N)')
    hold on

    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(valid_time2,valid_fzn2,'b.')
    title('Fzn vs time(Left Leg)')
    xlabel('time(s)')
    ylabel('Fzn(N)')
    hold on


    j = j + 1;
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: Hey there, i just tried curly and round brackets which it didnt work.

For the curly bracket {i}, it states that "Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object."

While the round bracket (i), states that "()-indexing must appear last in an index expression."

I looked through other examples, but my data are different from the others so I wouldnt know how to make it work.

Comment: What could be happening here is that you have a portion of code that isn't shown that assigns a value to x1, x2.... If they have previously been used, then you will probably need to rename the variable in order to allow for the cell assignment to work.

Comment: I see, the problem is that for the previous value to x1... were allocated using FOR loop as well, which was pretty challenging for me as I'm aiming to shorten the codes